# Problema con "log out" laravel

Tags: laravel, bootstrap

Hola a todos les pido ayuda porque acabo de crear y configurar el **auth** en laravel 8 y les pido ayuda ya que una vez iniciado sesión, en el boton que sale arriba a la derecha con el nombre del usuario no me sale el boton de **log out**, asi es como lo muestra:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando le doy clic no pasa nada, quiero aclarar que soy nuevo en laravel y solo se usar laravel 5 así que ¿en laravel 8 tengo que hacer algo mas para que lo muestre? o es un error por separado, por si es de relevancia este es mi **app.balde.php**:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- CSRF Token -->
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    <title>{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}</title>

    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Styles -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-white shadow-sm">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ url('/') }}">
                    {{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}
                </a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="{{ __('Toggle navigation') }}">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                    <!-- Left Side Of Navbar -->
                    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">

                    </ul>

                    <!-- Right Side Of Navbar -->
                    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                        <!-- Authentication Links -->
                        @guest
                            @if (Route::has('login'))
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('login') }}">{{ __('Login') }}</a>
                                </li>
                            @endif

                            @if (Route::has('register'))
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('register') }}">{{ __('Register') }}</a>
                                </li>
                            @endif
                        @else
                            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                                <a id="navbarDropdown" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" v-pre>
                                    {{ Auth::user()->name }}
                                </a>

                                <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('logout') }}"
                                       onclick="event.preventDefault();
                                                     document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
                                        {{ __('Logout') }}
                                    </a>

                                    <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" class="d-none">
                                        @csrf
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        @endguest
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>

        <main class="py-4">
            @yield('content')
        </main>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Desde ya gracias :).

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ intente lo que dijiste con quitarlo del dropdown y ponerlo directamente en el navbar pero no me lo mostraba, y no me deja abrir el dropdown, se queda como si ya lo tuviera abierto y no puedo darle clic

Comment: Esas clases parecen de bootstrap. Lo tienes instalado además de sus dependencias (como jquery)? En laravel 8, creo que  los presets vienen con tailwind, así que no sé como es que llegaste hasta ahí

Comment: Entonces ¿que tengo que instalar?, hasta ahora solo tengo en el header a jquery y boostrap, que tengo que hacer

Comment: Ah, ok. Ahí veo que estás cargando jquery por cdn, pero no veo el js de bootstrap, sólo los css. Si vas a usar los cdn, entonces no tienes que instalar nada, solo carga los archivos como está explicado en su página https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/getting-started/introduction/

Comment: Intentaste enviar el enlace a una funcion y que alla te espere un ```session()->flush();```
elimina todo lo que hay en la sesion y claro, que te retorne a la pagina principal

Comment: También recuerda que los scripts van al final justo antes del cierre de la etiqueta body

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ hice lo que dijiste de incluir los archivos js, y ya funciona el unico problema por llamarlo asi es que la flecha al lado del nombre del usuario se queda siempre viendo hacia abajo, creo yo que debería de ver a otro lado cuando no se esta mostrando el **log out** no? De todas formas gracias

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ son gusto agrego la respuesta pero, ¿la agrego aunque como mencione la flecha al lado del usuario siempre este viendo hacia abajo?

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ creo que lo de la flecha lo buscare en otro lugar y si no encuentro respuesta escribiré una pregunta aquí, entonces voy a escribir el como resolví mi problema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya lo resolví, me faltaba añadir los archivos **js** de **bootstrap** de forma que quedaría asi:

```
   <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-Piv4xVNRyMGpqkS2by6br4gNJ7DXjqk09RmUpJ8jgGtD7zP9yug3goQfGII0yAns" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Styles -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{{ asset('css/styles.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```